# Django translation files not generated inside locale directory in a specific app

Tags: django

I have no issue with running django-admin makemessages --all from the base directory and the .po files are being generated inside the locale directory in my main app but I have an issue with generating the same files in my specific apps.

my project looks like this

```
├── about_page ((but this one is not filled) 
  ___ en  
  ___ de
  ___ es
  ___ fr 
├── accessories
├── callibrators
├── careers
├── contact_page
├── db.sqlite3
├── dimensional_measurement
├── leak_testing
├── locale
   ___ en   (these files are filled with .po files)  
   ___ de
   ___ fr
   ___ es
├── manage.py
├── mysite
├── newsnevents_page
├── polls
├── products_page
└── services
```

my settings.py has

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')), 
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),


]


LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'about_page', 'locale'),
       

]






# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'about_page.apps.AboutPageConfig',
    'contact_page.apps.ContactConfig',
    'products_page.apps.ProductsPageConfig', 
    'careers.apps.CareersConfig',
    'newsnevents_page.apps.NewsneventsPageConfig',
    'dimensional_measurement.apps.DimensionalMeasurementConfig',
    'leak_testing.apps.LeakTestingConfig',
    'callibrators.apps.CallibratorsConfig',
    'services.apps.ServicesConfig',
    'accessories.apps.AccessoriesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_recaptcha',
    'rosetta', #NEW
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

when I execute this from the project's base directory

```
django-admin makemessages --all
```

the locale in base directory is filled but the about_page's locale directory is not filled with the translation files. Here I attached a view from the Rosetta site.

When I execute
django-admin makemessages --all , from the about_page app directory,

I get

```
kaan@kaan-GF63-Thin-11UC:~/kao_website/mysite/about_page$ django-admin makemessages --all
processing locale de
processing locale es
processing locale en
processing locale fr
```

but these files are empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been faced with the same problem as you. I solved it by writing the translation requests for the template in the views.
In your app view:

```
 output = _('Your text to translate')
```

Don't forget to add "output" in the context.

Run the makemessages -all command
You will find what you are looking for in the local po of your app.
Compile your translation and run the compilemessage command.

then in the template

```
{{ output }}
```

or

```
{% trans "Your text to translate" %}
```

In rosetta you will find the translations by clicking on the "third party" button.

Comment: I solved it already, I had forgot to update my settings.pay for the apps in my base directory. I appreciate for your efforts to reply. I will check your input on the topic.